# TemplateDoesNotExist at / new.html

Tags: django

i'm trying to connect the html file with my views.py although everything seem correct but still after running the server it shows TemplateDoesNotExist

This is the folder order

[image]

**views.url**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'new.html')
```

Comment: Make sure you have `TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]` in your `settings.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path should be

```
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'home/new.html')
```